# How to find out the accuracy result per label in evaluate()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, evaluate

I have data with 6 kinds of labels (let's say a, b, c, d, e, f) and use lstm for my calculations and model.evaluate to evaluate them. Then I want to know how the accuracy per label like classification report, but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

I tried to combine some code i got, but i get error. Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(hidden_units_masukan, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_masukan))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation=activation_masukan))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer_masukan, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary() 
history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=15, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=32, verbose=2)

predictions = accuracy
class_labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
max_test = np.argmax(testy, axis=1)
max_predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
class_report = metrics.classification_report(max_test, max_predictions, output_dict=True)

print('Classification report:\n', class_report)
```

Here is the error i got:

```
---> max_predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Comment: Can't you just run predict then apply np.argmax cause if i remember correctly evaluate does not return the predictions

Comment: As far as I know, predict() returns the final output of the model, while evaluate() returns the loss. And I need the loss value. I tried to use both at the same time but they produce different output. So I'm really confused how to solve it.